# Is it a mandate to write web.xml file for a Servlet program to run?

Tags: java, xml, servlets

Does **web.xml** ***`file`*** have to be physically present on the file for a Servlet program to run ?

Heard that in Tomcat 7.0, you don't need to write **web.xml** ***`file`*** explicitly as the `@WebServlet` `annotation` present in the Servlet class automatically builds the **web.xml** ***`file`*** internally..

If that is the case, what prompts the below program to output the following error message ?

> ***`HTTP Status 404 - /Show_Items`***
>
> ***`type`*** **Status report**
>
> ***`message`*** ***/Show_Items***
>
> ***`description`*** **The requested resource is not available.**
>
> *Could someone throw light on this?*

**Servlet file**

```
package com.foo.randomcode;


/*This file is connected to HTML file called Order_Form.html*/

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ShowItems_ArrayList
 */
@WebServlet("/Show_Items")
public class Show_Items extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Show_Items() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        ArrayList previousItems = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("previousItems");

        //session.getAttribute always return an Object, hence it is typecasted to match
        // receiving data type. 

        if(previousItems == null){
            previousItems = new ArrayList();

            session.setAttribute("previousItems", previousItems);

            //session.setAttribute(String name, String value)
            //The name should match with the associated value.

        }

        String newItem = request.getParameter("newItem");
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String title = "Items purchased";
        out.println("<html> \n" +
                    "<head><title>" +title+ "</head></title>" +
                    "<body bgcolor=\"#fdf5e6> \n" + 
                    "<h2>" +title+ "</h2>"

                    );

        synchronized (previousItems) {
            if(newItem !=null){
                previousItems.add(newItem);
            }

            if(previousItems.size()==0){
                    out.println("<i>No items</i>");
                }

            else {
                out.println("<ul>");
                for(int i=0; i<=previousItems.size(); i++){
                    out.println("<li>" +previousItems.get(i));
                }
                out.println("<ul>");
            }
        }

        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

**Order_Form**.***`html`***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Order Form</h3>

    <form action="com.foo.randomcode.Show_Items">
        <label> New Item to Order: <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="yacht" /> <br><br> 
            <input type="submit" value="Order & Show all Purchases">
        </label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

***Error stack trace*** : after changing `<form action="Show_Items">`

> 127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2015:16:41:01 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11418
>
> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Apr/2015:16:41:02 +0530] "GET /Runtime_Testing/Order_Form.html HTTP/1.1" 200 370
>
> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Apr/2015:16:41:06 +0530] "GET /Runtime_Testing/Show_Items?newItem=hello HTTP/1.1" 500 1585

***New error message:***

> HTTP Status 500 - Index:1, Size:1
>
> ***`type`*** **Exception report**
>
> ***`message`*** **Index: 1, Size: 1**
>
> ***`description`*** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> ***`exception`***
>
> ***`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`***
>   ***`java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)`***
>   ***`java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)`***
>   ***`com.foo.randomcode.Show_Items.doGet(Show_Items.java:68)`***
>   ***`javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)`***
>   ***`javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)`***
>   ***`org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)`***

**Final Output**

> ***`URL:`*** ***`http://localhost:8080/Runtime_Testing/Show_Items?newItem=computer`***

**// This is what is visible on the screen after program runs**

> ***`<body bgcolor="#fdf5e6> <h2>Items purchased</h2> <ul> <li> computer <ul> </body></html>`***

Comment: change form action to `action="/Show_Items"`

Comment: What `/Show_Items` represents inside `@WebServlet("/Show_Items")`? Do you understand the url mapping to Servlet.

Comment: `action` attribute of the `form` should point to the url mapped to the servlet.

Comment: @braj - url mapping to Servlet is one topic which I believe I couldn't understand to the fullest... Could you please elaborate a little ?

Comment: @Kishore - that's what I wanted to clarify. Is there a need to write a web.xml file ? 

If yes, then what should be the parameters passed to the `action` attribute of the `form' element and what should be the path of `<url-pattern>` ?? 

**Reply awaited.**

Comment: `web.xml` is not necessary if you are using annotations.
`@WebServlet(<url-pattern>)`. Have a look at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html

Comment: @Kishore - **_Perfect !!!_** What's stopping the program then from executing ?

Comment: @singhakash - did that, but to no effect. I couldn't figure it out what action would get me going ?

Comment: what IDE you are using?

Comment: **Eclipse Version:**  _Kepler Service Release 1_

**Build id:** _20130919-0819_

Comment: just right click on your servlet and choose option run on a server,it will give you null pointer on `.getParameter` but it will show you the actual url of servlet in browser

Comment: @singhakash - URL that is showing up on browser after running servlet file is : http://localhost:8080/Runtime_Testing/Show_Items

Comment: @singhakash : Output is rather funny:

`<body bgcolor="#fdf5e6> 
<h2>Items purchased</h2> 
<i>No items</i> </body></html>`

Comment: @singhakash - Actually, while I run HTML file, and input some text, its when I get the **HTTP Status 404**  `error` page.

Answer (score 1):

after java EE edition 6(which has servlet 3.0 specifications), you need not write `web.xml` file. You can annotate a servlet with @[WebServlet](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html). In the previous versions.

You need to do

```
 <form action="Show_Items">
```

it is mapped to `@WebServlet("/Show_Items")`

The `action` element should have the value of url pattern and not the servlet class itself. `@WebServlet` annotation maps url pattern to servlet class. It is like specifying `<servlet-mapping>` element in `web.xml`.

For the IndexOutOfBoundsException, change your for loop to

```
for(int i=0; i<previousItems.size(); i++)
```

in your previous condition `i<=previousItems.size()` returns the size as `1` i.e. total number of elements is only 1. But you are trying to access `previousItems.get(i)` where value of `i=1` which is the second element in list which does not simply exist. Remember that lists are zero index based.

After seeing your servlet code, it seems that you should follow the [MVC architecture with servlets and jsp](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/) there are certain [advantages of using jsp over servlets for showing output.](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/12/30/advantages-jsp-servlets/)

Comment: @kharkar - then whats wrong with the above program ?

Comment: @kharkar -  **HTTP Status 404**  `error` still persists, in spite of the changes applied.

Comment: @kharkar - **Yes.**  If a write a simple "Hello World" program in Servlet, it runs without any issue. However, when I write JSP/HTML file and try to link it, that's where the concern lies. 
**Did you try running this program at your end ?**

Comment: I do not have server setup on this machine. I am considering you are directly visiting the html page first. THen clicking submit button on it. and afterwards you facing this issue. Please check whether you are getting any stacktrace on the console. Also, please let me know the url in the browser for every action you perform

Comment: @kharkar - URL after you run the HTML file:
http://localhost:8080/Runtime_Testing/Order_Form.html

Comment: @kharkar - URL after inserting input & clicking on Submit button: 
http://localhost:8080/Show_Items?newItem=hello

and then follows the **HTTP Status 404** _error_ `page.`

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Show_Items is wrong. It should be something like http://localhost:8080/Runtime_Testing/Show_Items?newItem=hello.  Please check whether  you have correctly specified `<form action = "Show_Items">`. There should not be any slash. It denotes root

Comment: @mindfreak I have updated the answer. You need to change your for loop  conditions.

Comment: @kharkar - so near, but yet so far. The output seems to be getting printed, but along with the `<html>` elements.

Comment: @kharkar - Waiting for the last update on your side, before we could close this thread.

Comment: @mindfreak, oops...what do you need? I've lost track in 2 days

Comment: @kharkar - quite understandable, Weekend magic !!
do have a look at the edited post.. you would get a fair idea of what is needed?

Comment: as far as I know you need not write `<html><body>` tags in servlet, try after removing those elements. Also I've updated the answer to refer a link that follows MVC architecture. Better stick to it